# iOS - how to put Xcode console in gdb mode when using the simulator

Tags: debugging, console, gdb, ios

When I build and test on the device, the Xcode console automatically goes into gdb mode, which makes it much easier to do stack traces. However, when I test on the simulator the console does not use gdb. I've looked everywhere for a preference setting but can't find anything.

How can you use gdb when using the simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - must be in debug mode.